# Why dajngo Is asking me password 3 times in a custom User model Singup

Tags: django, django-models

Hi I think I messed up my custom User creation system.
Time ago it works fine but I dont know what I did, and it ended messed up.
Now in order to create a new user 3 PASSWORDS fiels are required

I have a custom user model that uses email instead of username like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser, BaseUserManager
from django.db import models
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    """Define a model manager for User model with no username field."""

    use_in_migrations = True

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a User with the given email and password."""
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a regular User with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password."""
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_staff=True.')
        if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
            raise ValueError('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.')

        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractUser):
    """User model."""

    username = None
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    phone = models.CharField(_('phone_number'),max_length=50,unique=True,null=True,blank=True)
    notify_email = models.BooleanField(_('notify_email'),default=False)
    notify_whats = models.BooleanField(_('notify_whats'),default=False)
 


    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

    objects = UserManager()
```

My form.py file is like this:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import AuthenticationForm, UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from django.forms.widgets import PasswordInput, TextInput
from .models import User



class CustomAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={
        'type':'text',
        'class':'form-control',
        'placeholder': 'Email',
        }))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={
        'type':'password',
        'class':'form-control',
        'placeholder':'Password',
        }))


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.EmailField(widget=TextInput(attrs={
        'type':'text',
        'class':'form-control',
        'placeholder': 'Email',
        }))
    password = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={
        'type':'password',
        'class':'form-control',
        'placeholder':'Password',
        }))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={
        'type':'password',
        'class':'form-control',
        'placeholder':'Reenter Password',
    }))
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',)
```

And when I pass to the templete like {{ form.as_p }} I ended with 3 password fields ALL REQUIRED.

When I print errors Django tells me: password, password1,password2 are required.
In fact if I fill all fields, It creates a new user but with no email field.
I have been hours trying to fix this problem or trying to complete reset my user model but I ended stuck.
Anyone can help me understard what is happening? THANKS FOR YOUR TIME!
[image]

Comment: The field names are `password1` and `password2`, not `password`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The field names are `password1` and `password2`, not <s>`password`</s>. By adding a `password` field, you thus introduce a third field. Your form thus should work with:

```
class CustomAuthForm(AuthenticationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={
        'type':'text',
        'class':'form-control',
        'placeholder': 'Email',
        }))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={
        'type':'password',
        'class':'form-control',
        'placeholder':'Password',
        }))


class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.EmailField(widget=TextInput(attrs={
        'type':'text',
        'class':'form-control',
        'placeholder': 'Email',
        }))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={
        'type':'password',
        'class':'form-control',
        'placeholder':'Password',
        }))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={
        'type':'password',
        'class':'form-control',
        'placeholder':'Reenter Password',
    }))
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username',)
```

Comment: Thanks man I should asked this 3h ago!